# Use POA in Acala-based fork

Tags: evm, acala

Acala is an EVM-substrate project.

I am trying to edit the code to make Acala run on POA not on POS as it is currently done.
What would be the steps to consider in order to shift to POA?

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? just to have an EVM chain, or is there anything specific about Acala? check Frontier

Comment: I want to have EVM + account mapping. Acala is just an option that i found. It seems there are also moobeam, astar etc. Does frontier allow account mapping such that if I send tokens to substrate account they will show up in the corresponding H160 account?

Comment: @katapulte Isn't Acala using Aura for consensus and already Proof of Authority?